# symfony: how to set properties and methods to be executed automatically when calling a doctrine model class?

Tags: php, model, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I would like to add some properties and methods to a Doctrine model class, so that every time an instance of this class is created, the properties are automatically set once, and can be accessed with the related getter, but these values are not stored in the database, instead they are calculated from other properties (these stored in the db) of the same class.

For instance let's say I have this class MyModel in the schema.yml:

```
MyModel:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  tableName: my_model
  columns:
    id:         { type: integer(8), primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true }
    quantity:   { type: decimal(12), scale: 3, notnull: true }
    price:      { type: decimal(12), scale: 3, notnull: true }
```

often I need to know the total amount, but I don't want to store it in the database: I could just do

```
class MyModel extends BaseMyModel
{
  public function getTotalAmount()
  {
    $this->total_amount = $this->getQuantity() * $this->getPrice(); 
  }    
}
```

and then every time I need to know the total amount, I can just call `$my_model->getTotalAmount()`.

However, I would like to have something like this

```
class MyModel extends BaseMyModel
{
  public function setTotalAmount()
  {
    $this->total_amount = $this->getQuantity() * $this->getPrice(); 
  }

  public function getTotalAmount()
  {
    return $this->total_amount;
  }
}
```

and when creating a new instance of the MyModel class like

```
$my_model = Doctrine_Core::getTable("MyModel")->find(1);
```

I would like the `setTotalAmount()` function to be executed automatically, so the `total_amount` value is calculated once and can be accessed with the `$my_model->getTotalAmount()` without having to recalculate it every time the function is called.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just plain wrong:

```
class MyModel extends BaseMyModel
{
  public function setTotalAmount()
  {
    $this->total_amount = $this->getQuantity() * $this->getPrice(); 
  }

  public function getTotalAmount()
  {
    return $this->total_amount;
  }
}
```

Setting a value means actually passing a parameter, and updating related field. Even if you update such value at hydration time, what if you change such values later, and you access `getTotalAmount`? Should you call `setTotalAmount` every time you update anything? No way.

```
class MyModel extends BaseMyModel
{
  public function getTotalAmount()
  {
    $this->total_amount = $this->getQuantity() * $this->getPrice(); 
  }    
}
```

This is totally right - you get a value based on two stored values, with maximum consistence.

Comment: well, what you point out is right, but you could then add a check, so that if the Doctrine_Record is in a DIRTY state, or just if at least one of the two parameters has been modified and not yet saved, then the total_amount is recalculate, otherwise the original value is retained. What do you think?

Comment: But the total amount is a simple product, why all this clutter? Just get it on demand, there is no overhead.

Comment: that is just an example, in the real case there are more properties to be set/accessed

Comment: As long as there aren't **very long and complex** operations to be performed, do everything in the getter, maybe caching it in a field after first request, yes. And if you have such operations, and there is chance you have to invalidate the cache **in the same controller**, you have a bad design problem.

Comment: ok, it did not exactly answer, but seems reasonable: thanks :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can [override the constructor](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/working-with-models.html#overriding-the-constructor) of your object. So it will be something like that:

```
class MyModel extends BaseMyModel
{
  private $total_amount = null;

  public function construct()
  {
    $this->setTotalAmount();
  }

  public function setTotalAmount()
  {
    $this->total_amount = $this->getQuantity() * $this->getPrice();
  }

  public function getTotalAmount()
  {
    if (null === $this->total_amount)
    {
      $this->setTotalAmount();
    }

    return $this->total_amount;
  }
}
```

Comment: The quantity and price properties are not set at the time `new MyModel` is called and the constructor is not called during`$em->getRepository('Path\To\Entities\MyModel')` however the `getTotalAmount` would be applicable until the quantity or price values change. At which point you would need to set `total_amount` to be null anytime they are changed.